# How do I unit test Flutter apps that initialize Firebase Core?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I have been trying to write unit tests for a Flutter app that initializes Firebase Core at the start.

I could not get a passing test so instead I simplified the test by ensuring that the app doesn't initialize and therefore perpetually displays a CircularProgressIndicator.

However, I can't even get that test to pass. Please help me identify why the test is not picking up that the loading spinner exists. I have altered my main code to start and keep the app in an error state and thus show the loading spinner. I have confirmed that this works in emulators.

```
    void main() {
  testWidgets('App smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Build our app and trigger a frame.
    await tester.pumpWidget(App());

    // Verify that our Sign In page shows first and has content.
    expect(
      find.byWidget(CircularProgressIndicator()),
      findsOneWidget,
    );
  });
}


void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  runApp(App());
}

class App extends StatefulWidget {
  _AppState createState() => _AppState();
}

class _AppState extends State<App> {
  // Set default `_initialized` and `_error` state to false
  bool _initialized = false;
  bool _error = true; //Start app in error state to always show Circular Progress Indicator.

  // Define an async function to initialize FlutterFire
  void initializeFlutterFire() async {
    try {
      // Wait for Firebase to initialize and set `_initialized` state to true
      await Firebase.initializeApp();
      setState(() {
        // _initialized = true; Commented out to keep app in error state.
      });
    } catch (e) {
      // Set `_error` state to true if Firebase initialization fails
      setState(() {
        // _error = true; 
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    initializeFlutterFire();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Show error message if initialization failed
    if (_error) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    // Show a loader until FlutterFire is initialized
    if (!_initialized) {
      return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
    }

    return MyFlutterApp();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [Firebase's Flutter testing documentation](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/testing/testing)?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I have. The documentation implies that you need it to test specific features (auth, firestore etc.). I'm just trying to get past initiliazation to test other parts of the app that aren't related. And in this example I'm loading a circularprogressindicator regardless of whether or not firebase succeeds in initializing so I think I must have written the test incorrectly?

Comment: It seems to me that the documentation says you're supposed to use fakes during testing, but that doesn't seem to be what you're using?